# How do I return information in a path in a multi-hop query?

Tags: nebula-graph

The example statement is as follows:

```
match (v1:player) -[:follow]->(v2:player)-[:serve]->(t:team) where v1.name == "tom" return v1.name, v2.name, t.name;
```

When the edge `serve` does not exist in `v2`, the whole statement does not return any data.

Can you tell me how to return `v1.name`, `v2.name` even if the `serve` edge of `v2` does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

To return v1.name and v2.name even if the serve edge of v2 does not exist, you can use an optional match clause in your NebulaGraph query.

For example:

```
match (v1:player) -[:follow]->(v2:player) /
optional match (v2)-[e:serve]->(t:team) /
where v1.name == "tom" /
return v1.name, v2.name, t.name;
```